# Colorbox : Keep the content fixed height and width

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am working in the html page using the colorbox, for my slideshow of gallery page. I want to keep the images in fixed height and width because the images are displayed with normal height and width.

The following is my code:

```
<a href="/img/slider/Slide9.jpg" class="button1 button2" title="" ><img src="/img/slider/Slide9.jpg"  alt="Feature-img" align="right" style="width:100%;height:240px;" /></a>
```

Any one help me.. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to the Script of your code.

```
           $(document).ready(function () {   
             $("a.button2").colorbox({maxWidth: '95%',maxHeight: '95%'});                
        });
```

Hope this will work for you ..!

For Reference, http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Put it under the script tags